# Is there any example to teach a machine understanding how to count with artificial nueral network?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

[Problem Statement]

Text: `By mass, oxygen is the third-most abundant element in the universe, after hydrogen and helium.`

Question: `What is the second most abundant element?`

Problem: `Find a machine learning model to teach machine understand how to count -- in this case it should count the most abundant element in the universe, (count here) 1 hydrogen 2 helium 3 oxygen, actually in text order should be oxygen (3) -> after -> hydrogen (1) -> helium (2). Thus machine should count 3 elements oxygen, hydrogen and helium and order them as (1) x (2) y (3) z or (1) x or y (3) z.`

Human perform well:

https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/explore/v2.0/dev/Oxygen.html

And as far as I know, by now, all model fail to answer the question.

Microsoft. https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/explore/1.1/dev/Oxygen.html?model=r-net+%20(ensemble)%20(Microsoft%20Research%20Asia)&version=1.1

Stanford University. https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/explore/1.1/dev/Oxygen.html?model=Logistic%20Regression%20Baseline%20(Stanford%20University)&version=1.1

Google AI Language. https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/explore/1.1/dev/Oxygen.html?model=BERT%20(ensemble)%20(Google%20AI%20Language)&version=1.1

The same to dataset 2.0 (models from Microsoft and Google AI give the same answer: no anwser)

Comment: To be fair, the text you list makes the answer ambiguous. It states that hydrogen and helium are the first and second most abundant elements, though does not explicitly state which is first and which is second. It is only in the full text (with the **additional** text `Oxygen is the most abundant element`) that you can discern that `helium` is indeed the second-most abundant element, as you know `1` and `3`, leaving only one option for `2`.

Comment: i think `after hydrogen and helium` and `after helium and hydrogen` are a little different: `oxygen is the third-most (3) abundant element in the universe, after -> (1) hydrogen -> (2) helium.` if change text to `after helium and hydrogen`, will be `oxygen is the third-most (3) abundant element in the universe, after -> (1) helium -> (2) hydrogen.` and if want to challenge that, okay, your answer can be `hydrogen or helium`